# Is it possible to remove sid from socket.io client get request to server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm fairly new to socket.io but I have been trying to figure out a way to remove the sid from the GET requests that the socket.io client sends to the server.

Example:

```
http://localhost:3333/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Mcx24JE&sid=pC6VHpJeXalrePERAAAB
```

I was hoping that the client's connect() call might except some parameters that would allow for one to hide the sid by issuing a POST instead of a GET but so far I haven't had much luck.

Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Why do you want to hide it? If you fear that a man in the middle could use it, use HTTPS.

Comment: In production we do have it going over HTTPS.  However our security team has still flagged it and are requiring that it be removed from the URL entirely despite HTTPS.

Comment: Why though? ... That doesnt make anything more secure (or I am missing something)

Comment: This was the reason they cited to me:  `The session ID may be disclosed via cross-site referer header. In addition, the session ID might be stored in browser history or server logs.`

Comment: Aah ... they do have a point there, haven't thought of that.